# Pavucontrol settings mystery

Tags: pulseaudio

1. How are the values of `Pavucontrol`'s default settings determined for a specific computer?
2. Where are Pavucontrol's settings stored?

Comment: search here .... https://github.com/pulseaudio/pavucontrol

Answer (score 0):

`pavucontrol` stores its settings in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pavucontrol.ini` (most likely you'll find the file in `~/.config/pavucontrol.ini`).

If you're looking for information on application or device settings, `pavucontrol` is just an interface to pulseaudio and doesn't actually store this information, so you'll have to start looking into `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pulse/`.